# Devexpress report : table repeating C#

Tags: c#, expression, report, devexpress, datamember

I have a report. I have created a table at design time and data is filled at runtime. When it's run, two tables are created for two rows. Either I need all data rows in one table row or add multiple table rows and fill the data rows in those.

My code: I just tried with one field AcName. Two rows are there: Asianet Broadband, Anoop. But they are created in separate tables not in the same table. DRTable is the detail report band.

```
report.DRTable.DataMember = query2.ToString();
//report.xrTable1.BeginInit();

report.AcName.ExpressionBindings.Add(new ExpressionBinding("BeforePrint", "Text", "[AcName]"));

// report.xrTable1.EndInit();
```

Summary also not displaying. I have given in the format expression:sumSum([Amt]) and summary :group.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. It sounds like you are calling the report twice. That would generate two tables.

Comment: can you describe issue in more detail? show designer layout, preview screenshot and expected result?

Comment: Issue got fixed with help of devexpress support.